# Silent Installation with MSI programs

Tags: windows-installer

I want to do a silent install on a .MSI extension but every time I run the script (.cmd ) it appears for 1 second and disappears directly but does not install anything.

Comment: Please show us your script

Comment: msiexec.exe /i "VNC-Viewer-6.22.826-Windows-en-64bit.msi"

Comment: you can use `%~dp0` to have the full path of your MSI an add `/qn` for a silent install : `msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0VNC-Viewer-6.22.826-Windows-en-64bit.msi" /qn`

Comment: it might also fail if the MSI needs admin rights (elevation) to install. You need to run the batch file from an elevated process